# How to Trace Who was Using my Mail Relay on Spamming?

Tags: postfix, email-server

I have a Postfix mail relay server running as Exchange smarthost as well as hosting another mail locally.

Last week I observed an attack on this server, someone is using it to send massive emails to different destinations.

I can't find out where it is connected from and the "from" address is also masked.

Below is the mail logs:

```
Apr 16 06:29:10 mail.xxx.com postfix/qmgr[25497]: EC5A91D727: from=<>, size=3096, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 16 06:29:10 mail.xxx.com postfix/bounce[12183]: B37D31D6FA: sender non-delivery notification: EC5A91D727
Apr 16 06:29:10 mail.xxx.com postfix/qmgr[25497]: B37D31D6FA: removed
Apr 16 06:29:11 mail.xxx.com postfix/smtp[12164]: 1A9B71D801: to=<xxx@inver**.com>, relay=inver**.com[164.138.x.x]:25, delay=50, delays=39/0/6.7/5, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 OK id=1lX6jh-000875-TC)
Apr 16 06:29:11 mail.xxx.com postfix/qmgr[25497]: 1A9B71D801: removed
Apr 16 06:29:11 mail.xxx.com postfix/smtp[11990]: 3BEAB1D9C3: to=<xxx@tms**.pl>, relay=tms**.pl[194.181.x.x]:25, delay=49, delays=37/0/6.7/5.4, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 OK id=1lX6ji-000469-QT)
Apr 16 06:29:11 mail.xxx.com postfix/qmgr[25497]: 3BEAB1D9C3: removed
Apr 16 06:29:12 mail.xxx.com postfix/smtp[12954]: 418621D80D: to=<xxx@medi**.com.cn>, relay=mxw**.com[198.x.x.x]:25, delay=51, delays=38/0/8.5/4.5, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mxw.mxhichina.com[198.11.189.243] said: 551 virus infected mail rejected (in reply to end of DATA command))
Apr 16 06:29:12 mail.xxx.com postfix/cleanup[7936]: 6711A1D7B7: message-id=<20210415182912.6711A1D7B7@mail.xxx.com>
Apr 16 06:29:12 mail.xxx.com postfix/bounce[12184]: 418621D80D: sender non-delivery notification: 6711A1D7B7
Apr 16 06:29:12 mail.xxx.com postfix/qmgr[25497]: 418621D80D: removed
Apr 16 06:29:12 mail.xxx.com postfix/qmgr[25497]: 6711A1D7B7: from=<>, size=2554, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 16 06:29:12 mail.xxx.com postfix/smtp[11499]: 65E4C1D95F: to=<xxx@an**.com>, relay=aspmx.l.google.com[172.217.x.x]:25, delay=51, delays=38/0/6.3/6.7, dsn=5.7.0, status=bounced (host aspmx.l.google.com[172.217.194.27] said: 552-5.7.0 This message was blocked because its content presents a potential 552-5.7.0 security issue. Please visit 552-5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BlockedMessage to review our 552 5.7.0 message content and attachment content guidelines. z63si3810735ybh.300 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
Apr 16 06:29:12 mail.xxx.com postfix/cleanup[10468]: 705F91D801: message-id=<20210415182912.705F91D801@mail.xxx.com>
Apr 16 06:29:12 mail.xxx.com postfix/smtp[11996]: F05911DBCA: to=<xxx@maq**.ae>, relay=maq**.protection.outlook.com[104.47.x.x]:25, delay=36, delays=27/0/3.1/6, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0 <20210415112836.BE31E4C0C57EAA1B@alshirak.com> [InternalId=93338229282509, Hostname=DB8PR10MB2745.EURPRD10.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM] 933811 bytes in 3.322, 274.451 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery)
Apr 16 06:29:12 mail.xxx.com postfix/qmgr[25497]: F05911DBCA: removed
Apr 16 06:29:12 mail.xxx.com postfix/bounce[12183]: 65E4C1D95F: sender non-delivery notification: 705F91D801
Apr 16 06:29:12 mail.xxx.com postfix/qmgr[25497]: 65E4C1D95F: removed
```

How to check where is the attack source? Is there a way to limit only a specific range of domains that can be used for mail relay?

I'm not a Postfix professional, so any suggestions/advises would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the message ID and grep on it.

For example, in the line below, the message ID is F05911DBCA.

```
Apr 16 06:29:12 mail.xxx.com postfix/qmgr[25497]: F05911DBCA: removed
```

So you can execute

```
$ grep F05911DBCA /var/log/maillog
```

It will list all postfix log lines about this message, so you can check all steps done by Postfix for this specific connection.

Also, grep for sasl_username to get the user account sending the message.
You can use "wc - l" command to get some count about how many times a account authenticated to send emails.

Figuring out what account was compromised, you can lock it out from sending emails.